# Vapor barrier on heated entertainment shed

Tags: insulation, mold, moisture, vapor-barrier

i am building an 8x10 entertainment shed with a loft for kids to hang out and have sleepovers in, i will be heating it. I have tyvek and t1-11 it is on 4x4 skids on top of the Concrete patio and has 3/4 plywood flr & sliding glass door,What do i use for vapor barrier and where and for insulation?

Comment: Where is this shed to be located? Country, state, city.

Comment: Not that closing and sealing all the gaps is more important than insulation... insulation important too though!

Answer (score 0):

The insulation goes in the stud bays between the studs. There are several options for insulation some of which are fiberglass bats, spray foam or solid foam  sheets.

Once the stud bays have been insulated then you cover the entire wall with a sturdy visqueen or plastic. 4mill will suffice, but 6mill can be used.

I like to staple the visqueen around the perimeter and leave enough so that it wraps around to the adjoining wall and ceiling and then staple and caulk that wall or the ceiling’s plastic on top of that.

For added Insurance  you could run a bead of caulk all the way around the perimeter of the wall before you staple the plastic on but you do not need the caulking on each stud.

If you puncture the plastic anywhere make sure you repair it with a suitable plastic tape.

Do a search on YouTube for [how to install vapor barrier](https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=how%20to%20install%20vapor%20barrier) in new construction and you will Have much information at your disposal.

Caveat: Not all information found on YouTube is correct so be sure to watch several videos,  And research in other places.

Comment: No, no, NO.  Do not put visqueen anywhere in your wall assembly.  This has long ago been shown to be the source of much of the mold and moisture problems of the era where we started to first make tighter houses, but didn't yet have the building science worked out.  Lots of old school contractors still think this is the thing to do - but do not.  What your climate is determines where your vapor control layer goes.  Even if you want it on the inside (very cold climate) it is much better to use a "smart" membrane.  An example: https://www.certainteed.com/building-insulation/products/membrain/

Comment: https://www.buildingscience.com/documents/digests/bsd-106-understanding-vapor-barriers

Answer (score 0):

Where is this shed to be located? Country, state, city.

With T1-11 being used you would not need separate sheathing (usu now OSB) over the studs outside so tyvek type housewrap would be nailed to the outside of the studs and the T1-11 nailed to the studs over that. On the inside would be fiberglass  bats with the kraft paper to the inside. This would allow the fiberglass to dry to the outside through the housewrap.

You could nail or screw drywall directly over the studs for good fire resistance. A more rugged interior would plywood or OSB instead of or under drywall, but this is more fuel for a fire.

Select a non flammable finish floor over the plywood.